# create dataframe by Iterating upto nth level of values in nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a json file downloaded from this link/website [human diseased icd-11 classification](https://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/download_htext?htext=br08403.keg&format=json&filedir=), this data have a upto 8 level of nesting e.g:

```
    "name":"br08403",
    "children":[
    {
        "name":"01 Certain infectious or parasitic diseases",
        "children":[
        {
            "name":"Gastroenteritis or colitis of infectious origin",
            "children":[
            {
                "name":"Bacterial intestinal infections",
                "children":[
                {
                    "name":"1A00  Cholera",
                    "children":[
                    {
                        "name":"H00110  Cholera"
                    }
```

I tried with this code:

```
def flatten_json(nested_json):
    """
        Flatten json object with nested keys into a single level.
        Args:
            nested_json: A nested json object.
        Returns:
            The flattened json object if successful, None otherwise.
    """
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out
df2 = pd.Series(flatten_json(dictionary)).to_frame()
```

output i'm getting is:

```
name    br08403
children_0_name 01 Certain infectious or parasitic diseases
children_0_children_0_name  Gastroenteritis or colitis of infectious origin
children_0_children_0_children_0_name   Bacterial intestinal infections
children_0_children_0_children_0_children_0_name    1A00 Cholera
... ...
children_21_children_17_children_10_name    NF0A Certain early complications of trauma, n...
children_21_children_17_children_11_name    NF0Y Other specified effects of external causes
children_21_children_17_children_12_name    NF0Z Unspecified effects of external causes
children_21_children_18_name    NF2Y Other specified injury, poisoning or cer...
children_21_children_19_name    NF2Z Unspecified injury, poisoning or certain..
```

but the desired output is a dataframe with 8 columns which can accommodate the last depth of the nested name key e.g. something like this:
[image]

I would really appreciate any help

code tried for extracting the 'name' property by created a dataframe as follows:

```
with open('br08403.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)

data = []
for a in range(len(df2)):
#     print(df2['children'][a]['name'])
    data.append(df2['children'][a]['name'])
    for b in range(len(df2['children'][a]['children'])):
#         print(df2['children'][a]['children'][b]['name'])
        data.append(df2['children'][a]['children'][b]['name'])
        if len(df2['children'][a]['children'][b]) < 2:
            print(df2['children'][a]['children'][b]['name'])
        else:
            for c in range(len(df2['children'][a]['children'][b]['children'])):
#                 print(df2['children'][a]['children'][b]['children'][c]['name'])
                data.append(df2['children'][a]['children'][b]['children'][c]['name'])
                if len(df2['children'][a]['children'][b]['children'][c]) < 2:
                    print(df2['children'][a]['children'][b]['children'][c]['name'])
                else:
                    for d in range(len(df2['children'][a]['children'][b]['children'][c]['children'])):
#                         print(df2['children'][a]['children'][b]['children'][c]['children'][d]['name'])
                        data.append(df2['children'][a]['children'][b]['children'][c]['children'][d]['name'])
```

but i'm getting a plain list as follows:

```
['01 Certain infectious or parasitic diseases',
 'Gastroenteritis or colitis of infectious origin',
 'Bacterial intestinal infections',
 '1A00  Cholera',
 '1A01  Intestinal infection due to other Vibrio',
 '1A02  Intestinal infections due to Shigella',
 '1A03  Intestinal infections due to Escherichia coli',
 '1A04  Enterocolitis due to Clostridium difficile',
 '1A05  Intestinal infections due to Yersinia enterocolitica',
 '1A06  Gastroenteritis due to Campylobacter',
 '1A07  Typhoid fever',
 '1A08  Paratyphoid Fever',
 '1A09  Infections due to other Salmonella',....
```

Comment: You need to look again at what you get from `flatten_json` and either convert that to the input you need, or use a different extraction function (which you may want to write yourself).  Where are you stuck with that process?

Comment: I created a dataframe using dictionary and tried to access name property in the each nested children property and append it to the list, but unable to append in a structured way.

Comment: updated the question with the effort for structured list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `pandas` only iterative approach.

```
res = requests.get("https://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/download_htext?htext=br08403.keg&format=json&filedir=")
js = res.json()

df = pd.json_normalize(js)
for i in range(20):
    df = pd.json_normalize(df.explode("children").to_dict(orient="records"))
    if "children" in df.columns: df.drop(columns="children", inplace=True)
    df = df.rename(columns={"children.name":f"level{i}","children.children":"children"})
    if df[f"level{i}"].isna().all() or "children" not in df.columns: break
```